# Facebook og image not changing even after re-scraping

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I dynamically generate images based on a product id and the image created has a name of something like 'fbshare_271' so the image name matches the unique product ID. When the product is updated, a new image is generated but the file name is still the same, so the old image is basically overwritten.

I have changed some details on the product expecting the correct details to show up when sharing, however it still shows the old image. I checked the image by going directly to the image path and the new image is there.

I have looked here on stack overflow and most of the answers say that going here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ and rescraping the url fixes the issue.

I have tried this repeatedly but still the old image is showing up. I thought of perhaps a timestamp or something but I don't want hundreds or thousands of images which is why I chose to just overwrite the existing image.

Comment: No, re-scraping usually doesn’t fix this issue, Facebook treats the OG image differently in that regard, than the shared URL itself. Your best bet it to append a URL parameter to the OG image URL (version number, timestamp of last change, sth. like that), and then get the document re-scraped.

Comment: I changed my echo statement to add `'?v=' . time()` and that seems to have worked so far!

Comment: @misorude, if you post that as your answer I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> most of the answers say that going here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ and rescraping the url fixes the issue.

No, re-scraping usually doesn’t fix this issue, Facebook treats the OG image differently in that regard, than the shared URL itself.

Your best bet it to append a URL parameter to the OG image URL (version number, timestamp of last change, sth. like that), and then get the document re-scraped.